# Multiple instances of btDefaultMotionState, all ignored, but one

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics, bulletphysics

To summarize the problem(s):

I have two bodies in my world so far, one being the ground, the other one being a falling box called "fallingStar".

1) I do not understand why my bullet world is not aligned with my drawn world unless I set an offset of `btVector3(2,2,2)` to the (btDefault)MotionState.
There is no fancy magic going on anywhere in the code that would explain the offset. Or at least I could not find any reason, not in the shaders, not anywhere.

2) I expected to be able to use multiple instances of `btDefaultMotionState`, to be precise, I wanted to use one instance for the falling entity and place it somewhere above the ground and then create another instance for the ground that should simply be aligned with my graphics-ground, ever unmoving.

What I am experiencing in regards to 2) is that for whatever reason the `btDefaultMotionState` instance for the falling entity is *always* also influencing the one for the ground, without any reference.

Now to the code:

Creation of the fallingBox:

```
btCollisionShape *fallingBoxShape = new btBoxShape(btVector3(1,1,1));
btScalar fallingBoxMass = 1;
btVector3 fallingBoxInertia(0,0,0);
fallingBoxShape->calculateLocalInertia(fallingBoxMass, fallingBoxInertia);

// TODO this state somehow defines where exactly _ALL_ of the physicsWorld is...
btDefaultMotionState *fallMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0,0,0,1), btVector3(2,2,2)));
//btDefaultMotionState *fallMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState();
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo fallingBoxBodyCI(fallingBoxMass, fallMotionState, fallingBoxShape, fallingBoxInertia);
/*btTransform initialTransform;
initialTransform.setOrigin(btVector3(0,5,0));*/
this->fallingBoxBody = new btRigidBody(fallingBoxBodyCI);
/*fallMotionState->setWorldTransform(initialTransform);
this->fallingBoxBody->setWorldTransform(initialTransform);*/
this->physicsWorld->addBody(*fallingBoxBody);
```

Now the interesting parts to me are the necessary offset of `btVector3(2,2,2)` to align it with my drawn world and this:

```
btTransform initialTransform;
initialTransform.setOrigin(btVector3(0,5,0));
this->fallingStarBody = new btRigidBody(fallingStarBodyCI);
fallMotionState->setWorldTransform(initialTransform);
```

If I reenable this part of the code *ALL* the bodies again show an offset, but **NOT** just 5 up, which I could somehow comprehend if for whatever reason the worldTransform would effect every entity, but about 2,2,2 off... which I cannot grasp at all.

I guess that this line is useless:

`fallMotionState->setWorldTransform(initialTransform);` as it does not change anything whether it's there or not.

Now to the code of the ground creation:

```
btCompoundShape *shape = new btCompoundShape();

... just some logic, nothing to do with bullet

btTransform transform;
transform.setIdentity();

transform.setOrigin(btVector3(x + (this->x * Ground::width),
                          y + (this->y * Ground::height),
                          z + (this->z * Ground::depth)));

btBoxShape *boxShape = new btBoxShape(btVector3(1,0,1)); // flat surface, no box

shape->addChildShape(transform, boxShape);
```

(this portion just creates a compoundshape for each surface tile :)

```
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo info(0, nullptr, shape);
return new btRigidBody(info);
```

Here I purposely set the motionstate to `nullptr`, but this doesn't change anything.

Now I really am curious... I thought maybe the implementation of `btDefaultMotionState` is a singleton, but it doesn't look so, so... why the hell is setting the motionState of one body affecting the whole world?

[image: offset without btVector3(2,2,2) for btDefaultMotionState]

[image: offset with btVector3(2,2,2) for btDefaultMotionState]

[image: The position of my box and it's body, also an offset]

Comment: Could it be that you are deleting `fallMotionState` after creating the `fallingBoxBody` rigid body? That would lead to a dangling pointer in the rigid body that could alias the next allocation of the same size, possibly causing what you are seeing? Either that, or you have some other previous dangling pointer that is getting stomped on by `fallMotionState`

Comment: @Frank well this happens in a constructor and it goes out of scope later, but I am not freeing anything manually here. (yes, possible cause for leakage)

Comment: Switched everything to use smart-pointers, still no luck

Answer (score 2):

Bullet is a good library but only few dedicate time to write good documentation.

To set position of a `btRigidBody`, try this :-

```
btTransform transform = body -> getCenterOfMassTransform();
transform.setOrigin(aNewPosition); //<- set orientation / position that you like
body -> setCenterOfMassTransform(transform);
```

If your code is wrong *only* at the set transformation part (that is what I guess from skimming your code), it should be solved.

Note that this snippet works only for dynamic body, not static body.

**About CompoundBody:-**

If it is a compound body, e.g. shape `B` contains shape `C`.
Setting transformation of `B` would work (set body of `B`), but not work for `C`.
 (because `C` is just a shape, transformation support only body.)

If I want to change relative transformation of `C` to `B`, I would create a whole new compound shape and a new rigid body.  Don't forget to remove old body & shape.

That is a library limitation.

**P.S.**

I can't answer some of your doubt/questions, these information are what I gathered after stalking in Bullet forum for a while, and tested by myself.

(I am also coding game + game library from scratch, using Bullet and other open sources.)

### **Edit: (about the new problem)**

> it just slowly falls down (along with the ground itself, which should
>   not move as I gave it a mass of 0)

I would try to solve it in this order.

**Idea A**

- Set to the compound mass = 0 instead, because setting a child shape's mass has no meaning.

**Idea B**

- First check `-> getCenterOfMassTransform()` every time-step , is it really falling?
- If it is actually falling, to be sure, try `dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0,0,0));`.
- If still not work, try with very simple world (1 simple object, no compound) and see.

**Idea C**     (now I start to be desperate)

- Ensure your camera position is constant.
- If the problem is still alive, I think you now can create a simple test-case and post it in Bullet forum without too much effort.
- Lower amounts of lines of code = better feedback

Comment: your position input brought me new problems, but I have something to look at. Funny thing is: If I do set a hardcoded position in there I'd assume that the body would simply stay there, right? Well, it does not... it just slowly falls down (along with the ground itself, which should not move as I gave it a mass of 0) Out of ideas

Comment: @Sorona My first bounty, thank!  I have add some ideas about the new problem at the end of answer.   :)

Comment: I am setting the mass on the body of course, not on any shape. If I set no gravity, of course it will not fall. It also only falls if there is the other body in there. If it's only the ground it stays (but completely offset)... maybe it has to do with the camera, gonna check.

Comment: @Sorona I never succeed to control world gravity, so I always set world gravity = 0 and use direct impulse per object instead (manually). ......  "only falls if there is the other body in there" It indicates that the the falling force might be from collision impulse (from a certain pair of object).  I have met a bug that such unknown velocity come from the collision at the first time-step (so the bug is very hard to be found).  Try to change position of another object at 0 time-step to very far away / add some collision callback to check.

Comment: @Sorona  Another guess : I hope you didn't set/modify mass of a (compound) body after add it to the world.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not normal bullet behavior. Your understanding of the library is correct.

What you are most likely dealing with is either a buffer overrun or a dangling pointer. The code you have posted does not have an obvious one of either, so it would be coming from somewhere else in your codebase. You might be able to track that down using a well-placed memory breakpoint.

You "might" be dealing with a header/binary version inconsistency issue, but that's less likely as you would probably be seeing other major issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the exact same type of behavior with the DebugDrawer suspended on top of the world. Solved it by passing to Bullet Physics the projectionview matrix alone, without the model matrix that he has and multiplies with already:

```
glUseProgram(shaderID);

m_MVP = m_camera->getProjectionViewMatrix();
glUniformMatrix4fv(shaderIDMVP, 1, GL_FALSE, &m_MVP[0][0]);
if (m_dynamicWorld) m_dynamicWorld->debugDrawWorld();
```